# when pthread_attr_t is not NULL?

Tags: c, multithreading, arguments, pthreads, posix

All parameters for pthread_create from POSIX threads are pretty straightforward to understand, except ***pthread_attr_t***. What is ***pthread_attr_t*** for, how, and when it is supposed to be not initialized by ***NULL***?

I went through the Linux [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). The description I found about ***pthread_attr_t*** is:

- Syntax:

  ```
  int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void*),void *arg);
  ```
- Explanation:

  ```
  The attr argument points to a pthread_attr_t structure whose contents
  are used at thread creation time to determine attributes for the new
  thread; this structure is initialized using pthread_attr_init(3) and
  related functions.  If attr is NULL, then the thread is created with
  default attributes.
  ```

Which is very unclear. I also googled all over the internet, and no clear explanation to be found anywhere either. So, when ***pthread_attr_t*** is not ***NULL***?

Can someone please shed some light about that? All comments and feedback are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it to created a detached (non-joinable) thread, or to set the thread's stack size to a non-default value, amongst other attributes.

See the POSIX specifications for:

- [`pthread_attr_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_init.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setguardsize()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setguardsize.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setinheritsched()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setinheritsched.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setschedparam()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setschedparam.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setschedpolicy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setschedpolicy.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setscope()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setscope.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setstack()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setstack.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setstacksize()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html)

(There are two functions per URL — `pthread_attr_destroy()` and 'get' analogues to the 'set' functions.)

Most often, you don't need to modify these.  Passing a NULL pointer to `pthread_create()` is equivalent to using a default set of attributes — which is what `pthread_attr_init()` creates for you.  You can change the attributes that you wish to change in the `pthread_attr_t` object via the functions and then pass that modified object to `pthread_create()` instead.

> Another thing that there is no apparent justification either, is the first argument from `pthread_create` on `pthread_t` data type definition.

All the POSIX thread types are opaque — that was a deliberate design decision by the POSIX committees.  You can't poke around inside the type portably.  This makes it easier for the implementation — you can only do what the functions allow you to do.  Ultimately, it simplifies life for the programmers (users) too; you don't get tricked into using internal knowledge of the POSIX implementation that won't migrate to other systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your enlightening answer. You mentioned: "to created a detached (non-joinable) thread"... then I followed your suggestion and found this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202762/pthread-create-as-detach‌​ed and also found more on why or when to have thread detached: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756882/detached-vs-joinable-posix-threads . Thank you!